# "npm start" works fine, while "expo start" raise an error saying that "expo" is not found

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, npm, expo

When I ran `npm start` on my project, everything works properly. However, when I try to run `expo start` instead, or any command using expo, it raises the following errors.

```
> expo --version
expo: The term 'expo' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have installed "expo-cli" successfully, and added BOTH `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` and  `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin` to the path.

I've tried to

1. re-install the `expo-cli`,
2. restart the terminal and computer after re-install it.

None of the above works for me.

And the scripts in my `package.json` are

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
```

The version of NodeJs is v16.13.1.

The version of npm is 8.3.0.

What I am most confused about is that for `npm start`, actually, it will call `npm start` in it to start. How can `expo start` raise an error while `npm start` is working fine?

Thank you all in advance!!

**Update**:

Here is the result when I ran `npm install --global expo-cli`.

```
> npm install --global expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.0.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which 
is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which 
is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which 
is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which 
is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which 
is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such 
as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead 

changed 1620 packages, and audited 1621 packages in 1m

113 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

27 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 9 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: Looks like expo isn't in your path.

Comment: Did you insall expo-cli globally?

Comment: run below command to install expo globally.
npm install --global expo-cli
and then open new terminal and check expo --version to make sure expo is available on right path.

Comment: @tromgy Hi! I did install the expo-cli globally. Here is the command "npm install -g expo-cli".

Comment: @user15517071 Hi! Then how can I add the path? Would it be the path of the "expo-cli" in the folder "node_modules" in my project?

Comment: @Dipten Hi, Dipten! Thank u for the advice. I've updated the warnings that I got when installing "expo-cli". I assume that I have installed it successfully. However, it still raises an error.

Comment: As you're using windows os so may require to restart once after making installation and environment variable changes.
as it works fine in Ubuntu though.

Comment: @Dipten OMG!!!!! Thank you so much! After restarting my computer, it works!!!!

Comment: @amy Glad to hear that works for you.